# How to verify Digitally Signed XML File?

Tags: c#, xml, hash, digital-signature

Hi i am very new to Digital Signing.I am verifying Digitally Signed XML File and i have verified it using the following code. But i want to know how it is verifying if the XML is proper or tampered. After going through some articles i found that 
1. Create hash for the XML.(Excluding signature part)
2. Decrypt Signature using public key(you will get a hash value)
3. Compare both the hash. (If both the hash matches then the XML is not tampered).
My understanding is right?.

This is the signature part of my XML

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>u+1NVN5c3gbaxmIrkO9SzVQDklA=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>QtQJjevrggzsFZj7PqD3p7GaWkzJAfyacjbMgMXgszCuO+Pxe2rrkScqvgGt2DJqgVlTbC/m9gnodCu7BcXSmW459mSJtyGH+ekWwj6g9ej8I7IYWCRqbI5uus3r3+vr/8ECd5CP/khu/LcCMyPuNIxA8h2EywCeQgbXBvLiWcdexBazdKQQpFxlKw0i+oTs8Ou6jViOdX1ZmTRtdKCQXzAElvpyNimQSmO9OECEs/TytjzIG98mpldfdofoq/2JC+xQhs6IF+Ctw/zlJdkgj1U18U/00Cw4puT4oScTELNSihSS+i9gAL+YjZLlIeunACbnZ4B1CVL/uS9kLlutXQ==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <KeyValue>
        <RSAKeyValue>
          <Modulus>kHORMZQYOifL5UdIhKe54SfvJKyzLL5Aaw9MgpzeQPgBMmD9KMRnkeU+5RYMiUW8GT3q4eW77UihyxSX3MTAHzuqXoc6GjkBO1Tr41isud721SG7iMspw829YZKAHAPDAl0BV5gpLZagH8KXrDp4dVU+XDOOLZZZWZnbpKSFKvLaJO34KphZ/9W3L/l1BOwEs7132svmtwGgPO2Y16C90sDRWp78ZCYYhb7fAez7683+fijZCDGuVTvS0lBKhmH0ETiNfBAiELUUwHvQ5GHOFSp5PA8+hV9F7zxno1a0/OBpRsHfLydm3THyMUS7DlPE46zPiO9rRIUe90aQ64ulYQ==</Modulus>
          <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
        </RSAKeyValue>
      </KeyValue>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
```

And how i am verifying the XML:

```
private void btnVerifySign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string  LModulus = node.SelectSingleNode("//Signature/KeyInfo/KeyValue/RSAKeyValue/Modulus").InnerText.ToString();
                string LExponent = node.SelectSingleNode("//Signature/KeyInfo/KeyValue/RSAKeyValue/Exponent").InnerText.ToString();
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
                {
var rsaParam = new RSAParameters()
                    {
Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(LModulus),
                        Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(LExponent)
                    };
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
bool result = VerifyXml(newxml1, rsa);
}

public static Boolean VerifyXml(XmlDocument Doc, RSA Key)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (Doc == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Doc");
            if (Key == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Key");

            // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it 
            // the XML document class.
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(Doc);

            // Find the "Signature" node and create a new 
            // XmlNodeList object.
            XmlNodeList nodeList = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

            // Throw an exception if no signature was found. 
            if (nodeList.Count <= 0)
            {
                // throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.");
                MessageBox.Show("Verification failed: No Signature was found in the document.");
            }

            // This example only supports one signature for 
            // the entire XML document.  Throw an exception  
            // if more than one signature was found. 
            if (nodeList.Count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.");
                // throw new CryptographicException("Verification failed: More that one signature was found for the document.");
            }

            // Load the first <signature> node.  
            signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

            // Check the signature and return the result. 
            return signedXml.CheckSignature(Key);
        }
```

Here if i modify the xml and verify it through VerifyXml method it returns false and if i dont modify the xml VerifyXml method returns true. I want to know how it is validating the XML? I have tried comparing the values for tampered and untampered XML in nodeList[0] and i got the same value but signedXml.CheckSignature(Key) is returning true/false. Digest values should be different for different xml right? Here i am getting the same digest value for modified and unmodified xml. And based on what exactly CheckSignature(Key) is returning true/false. And when the hash value is created for xml?. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is `<SignedInfo>` element that is signed, not the data object. Hash of data object is included in the `<Reference>` element of the `<SignedInfo>` element. Therefore data object is also indirectly signed. When verifying signature, hash value of the data object is compared to signed digest of data in the `<Reference>` element. Then signature on `<SignedInfo>` element is checked using the public key.

For more information you can read [RFC 3275](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3275). There you can find information on steps performed for both generation and validation of signed xml.

Comment: But here <Reference> element is null. What does it mean? Hash of data object is not generated?

Comment: @Rakesh In your example `<Reference>` element is not null. It contains `<Transforms>`, `<DigestMethod>` and `<DigestValue>` elements. `<DigestValue>` contains hash of data object, generated using algorithm defined in `<DigestMethod>`. In section 4.3.3 of  RFC 3275 it is said that _Reference is an element that may occur one or more times_. Also you can find description of `<Reference>` element's content in that section.